# How to combine find, ssh and rsync to transfer files by timestamp

Tags: bash, ssh, find, rsync

I want to transfer automatically files of last 24 hours from Remote Server to Local Server (both GNU linux). I've been trying a lot with `find` and `rsync` commands (and `ssh`) separately, and now I'm only able to:

**1-)** Get the list of last 24 hours files in directory `/FilesInRemoteServer/` on Remote Server using "find and ssh"

**2-)** Transfer successfully files using `rsync` and `ssh` from Remote to Local server

My issue now is that I cannot combine `find`, `ssh` and `rsync`. I mean I cannot combine the output of last 24 hour's files given by `find` in order that `rsync` takes that 
list of files I want to transfer from `stdin`.

*This is what I've done so far:*

**(1)** `ssh` and `find` command (command sent in Local Server)
    With this combination of `ssh` and `find` I'm able to get the list of files of last 24 hours:

```
ssh root@192.168.X.X 'find /FilesInRemoteServer/ -mtime -1 -type f -printf %P\\0'
```

**(2)** rsync and ssh command (command sent in Local Server)
    With "rsync" in combination with "ssh" I can copy from Remote Server to Local Server the files from directory "/FilesInRemoteServer" in this way:

```
rsync -avzhe ssh root@192.168.X.X:/FilesInRemoteServer/ "/DestinationInLocalServer/"
```

But when I try to combine both commands (1 and 2) is not working and get this error:

```
ssh root@192.168.X.X 'find /FilesInRemoteServer/ -mtime -1 -type f -printf %P\\0' |
rsync -avzhe --files-from=- -0 ssh root@192.168.X.X:/FilesInRemoteServer/ \
      "/DestinationInLocalServer/" 
Unexpected remote arg: root@192.168.X.X:/FilesInRemoteServer/
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1330) [sender=3.1.1]
root@192.168.X.X's password:
```

Thanks for any help.

**# Update:**

Hello, again when I try both commands separately they work, but if I test like you suggest it asks 3 times the SSH password and I get permission denied and errors below.

```
$ ssh root@192.168.X.X 'find /FilesInRemoteServer/ -mtime -1 -type f -printf %P\\0' | rsync --archive --verbose --compress --human-readable --files-from=- --from0 --rsh=ssh root@192.168.X.X:/FilesInRemoteServer/ /DestinationInLocalServer/
root@192.168.X.X's password: root@192.168.X.X's password:

Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.168.X.X's password: Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.168.X.X's password:

Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.168.X.X's password: Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.168.X.X's password:

Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.1]
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Comment: I don't understand why your rsync line includes "`ssh`"... Also have a look on this Unix StackExchange [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11170).

Comment: Hi Amessihel, I include ssh within rsync to add encryption security while transfering.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question. The approach is cleaner than what I had been doing!

Comment: I am trying following command

ssh -i digital.pem ubuntu@SERVER_IP 'find /home/user/import_live/content/* -mtime -5 -type f -name "*.xml" -printf %P\\0' | rsync -rtuzv -e 'ssh -i digital.pem' --files-from=- --from0 ubuntu@SERVER_IP:/home/user/import_live/content/* /home/user/test/

I am getting error like this.
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at options.c(2308) [server=3.1.1]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.1]

Answer (score 2):

Before using a utility, you should understand what all the options you're providing it will do. In your case, you're using the `-e` option. What does the man page have to say about this?

> ```
>   -e, --rsh=COMMAND
>           This option allows you to choose an alternative remote shell program to use for communication between the  local
>           and  remote copies of rsync. Typically, rsync is configured to use ssh by default, but you may prefer to use rsh
>           on a local network.
>
>           If this option is used with [user@]host::module/path, then the remote shell COMMAND will be used to run an rsync
>           daemon  on  the  remote host, and all data will be transmitted through that remote shell connection, rather than
>           through a direct socket connection to a running rsync daemon on the remote host.  See the section "USING  RSYNC-
>           DAEMON FEATURES VIA A REMOTE-SHELL CONNECTION" above.
> ```

So, `-e` is expecting an argument. It gets one in your first command:

```
rsync -avzhe ssh root@192.168.X.X:/FilesInRemoteServer/ "/DestinationInLocalServer/"
```

But in your second, you decided not to give it an argument:

```
rsync -avzhe --files-from=- -0 ssh root@192.168.X.X:/FilesInRemoteServer/ \
  "/DestinationInLocalServer/"
```

I'm sure if you call it properly it will start working again. I find using the long version of options is a good way to remember what they're doing:

```
ssh root@192.168.X.X 'find /FilesInRemoteServer/ -mtime -1 -type f -printf %P\\0' |
rsync --archive --verbose --compress --human-readable --files-from=- --from0 \
    --rsh=ssh root@192.168.X.X:/FilesInRemoteServer/ \
    "/DestinationInLocalServer/"
```

Comment: Your final command is a little off. `--rsh=ssh` should set the remote shell command, and `root@192...` is the source. As you've written it, the remote shell command consists of ssh plus an invalid argument, `"/Destination...` is the source, and there is no destination. Note that `--files-from` does not specify a source, it merely provides a list of files *at* the source.

Comment: Thanks, spurious quotes removed!

Comment: Hi miken32, thanks for your answer. I´ll try on monday your suggestion hoping it will work.

Comment: Hello miken32, thanks for the help. I've tried and I get permission denied. Please see the update part in my original post.

Comment: Yes of course you'll still get prompted to enter a password if you don't have public key authentication set up on your remote server.

Comment: I am getting syntax error (on mac OS X): rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at options.c(2349) [client=3.1.2], the code is below

Comment: ssh root@x.x.x.x 'find /home/user/downloads -newermt 2016-06-20 -type f -printf %P\\0' | rsync --dry-run --archive --verbose --compress --human-readable --files-from=- --from0 \ --rsh=ssh root@x.x.x.x:/home/user/downloads/ \ "/Volumes/Data/"